# External SSD drive fails to respond after some frequent writes

Tags: catalina, ssd, external-disk

I am using a Sandisk SSD.

It has happened a few times already in last two days. After some frequent writes, suddenly I will have trouble accessing the drive.

In the latest occurance, I did not read from or write to the disk for about 3 hours.

Output from `mount`

```
/dev/disk3s1 on /Volumes/ExtremeSSD (apfs, local, nodev, nosuid, journaled, noowners)
```

More info from Disk utility

[image]

Just a FYI, here is the info of my main SSD:

[image]

What I can see in the log

```
default 07:18:36.860460+1000    kernel  disk3: I/O error.
default 07:18:36.860479+1000    kernel  nx_buf_bread:592: buf_biowait() failed, error = 5, b_error = 5, buf_flags_after_io = 0x101, crypto = [unencrypted  ]
default 07:18:36.860487+1000    kernel  _vnode_dev_read:811: *** got err 5 reading blknum 28635 (num read errs: 377524)
default 07:18:36.860502+1000    kernel  apfs_vnop_blockmap:10831: ### obj-id 537613/537613 err 5 offset 0 size 131072 mapflags 2 dstream 2364702/2883584 ###
default 07:18:36.880386+1000    kernel  disk3: I/O error.
```

If I want to eject the disk, it will take many trials to force eject it, despite I have ensured no application is using the drive.

Here is how I use the drive:

I wrote up a python script which downloads files and write to a directory which is symlinked to a folder on the SSD drive.

At the time of writing this I can see a lot of errors from `python` like

```
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '10000_files/1vVwd9tQQw6DAaRCgtQB.data.FD2A0e73' -> '110000_files/1vVwd9tQQw6DAaRCgtQB.data'
```

or

```
[Errno 5] Input/output error
```

How can I improve the stability of the drive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usb-c cable was faulty. That's why the read/write started to fail after a certain duration of high volume data transfer.

Once I replaced the usb-c cable that connects the SSD drive to the MBP, and the SSD drive is working as expected.

Comment: So, basically, it was a physical problem with the drive as I described in my answer.

Answer (score -1):

A *disk I/O error* means that the operating system (in this case macOS, but applies to every OS) is having difficulty executing a read/write command of the physical device.  Note:  this is not that it doesn't understand what it's reading but that it cannot read it.  It's the difference between looking through a window in a house and not understanding the [feng shui](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feng_shui) and looking through the same window and not seeing anything because the window is boarded up or covered with dirt and grime.

> How can I improve the stability of the drive?

**You can't because it has failed.  You need to get a new drive.**

It could be the USB controller or the NAND flash chips.  Unless you disassemble everything at test out each component, it's impossible to tell.